# General security request setup

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

Im trying to completely eliminate any chance of repainting or false signals in my script and just wanted some advice on the best way to set up a security request.

Is it best to have each bool statement defined outside the security request or is it the same as having them defined within the request,  below is the 2 options

Alerts are being set on the 1 Minute Chart

```
// EXAMPLE 1
f_get_SR2() => [close>open, close<open[1], open[1]]

[M5_Bullish , M5_Ab_Last_Open, m5_Lastopen] = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, '5' , f_get_SR2() ,  barmerge.gaps_off,  barmerge.lookahead_on)

//OR

Bullish       = close>open
Und_Last_Open = close<open[1]
Last_Open     = open[1]
f_get_SR2() => [Bullish , Und_Last_Open  , Last_Open   ]

[M5_Bullish , M5_Ab_Last_Open, m5_Lastopen] = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, '5' , f_get_SR2() ,  barmerge.gaps_off,  barmerge.lookahead_on)
```

Say i want to see if the last 1 minute bar is above the last 5m bar open
Do I have to request it within the tuple as close<open[1] or is it the exact same outcome if i request the open within the tuple and then write it as

```
// On the 1 minute chart
M5_Ab_Last_Open = close>m5_Lastopen and barstate.isconfirmed
```

```
//EXAMPLE 2
K_down      = k[1]<k[2]
Macd_down   = macd[1]<macd[2]
hist_down   = hist[1]<hist[2]
Long_Sell   = (K_down     or macd[1]<macd[2])  and  hist_down
f_get_tf4() =>  
    [ Long_Sell    , K_down  ] 

[TF4_L_SellSig_NR, TF4_lastk_Dn] = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, '60', f_get_tf4(),  barmerge.gaps_off,  barmerge.lookahead_on)

//OR

f_get_tf4() =>  
    [(k[1]<k[2]  or macd[1]<macd[2])  and  hist[1]<hist[2], k[1]<k[2]] 

[TF4_L_SellSig_NR, TF4_lastk_Dn] = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, '60', f_get_tf4(),  barmerge.gaps_off,  barmerge.lookahead_on)
```

I have it set to barmerge.gaps_off,  barmerge.lookahead_on  because some of the requests i need live data ( but they arent included in the alerts) only confirmed ones... [1] etc

```
//Would this repaint if set on a 1 minute chart?
Up_2perc = (close>(open*0.98))

[Hour_Up_2 ] = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, '60', UP_2perc ,    barmerge.gaps_off,  barmerge.lookahead_on) 

if UP_2perc and barstate.isconfirmed
    strategy.entry('Long'..................
```

I know its probably best to do all calculations within the security request but some data figures might be used for a variety of different calculations.
I just want to check if there is any major difference in the way the data is received or if the end result would be the same any of the ways used above.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To avoid repainting, use the `f_secureSecurity()` function from [this library](https://www.tradingview.com/script/cyPWY96u-How-to-avoid-repainting-when-using-security-PineCoders-FAQ/)